# Daz character import - sharp bones/mesh

Tags: mesh, armature, export, transforms, import

Could anybody provide a solution to this please

I've imported a Daz Genesis8 female into blender using the official bridge - which I do like.  When moved into a certain pose position, i.e bend at knees. The knees have quite a sharpness and looks off

rendered at sub division level 3
I know the lighting doesn't help
Any suggestions to what I might be doing wrong, maybe import settings?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is an incomplete answer, but I can't use "comment" to add a python script that I'll reference.

I have done quite a bit of DAZ importing and indeed is has improved over time.   I would try to re-parent the character mesh to armature... however often bones like IK are set incorrectly to Deform, which will cause other problems.  So I use a script like the following to negate any incorrect setting of Deform.

```
import bpy
for arm in bpy.data.armatures:
    for bone in arm.bones:
        if bone.name.find('IK') != -1:
            bone.use_deform = False
```

However, sometimes the Envelope Distance or Radii are set incorrectly by the DAZ-export blender-import, thus also leading to distortions.

So, thorough testing (of some extreme poses) would be a good approach.

I also often find that many Limit-Rotation or locks on bone scaling are missing, which allows IK positioning to stretch bones, causing other character distortions.

I have also found clothing that is attached using Armature child is wanting -- I correct these by switching to *Surface Deform*, binding to the character mesh.  That way character doesn't poke through clothing in some extreme poses.

Also -- an aside -- all of the materials using images (characters, clothing) will be pointing into DAZ directories... You may want to consider *File >> External Data >> Pack Resources*  if you ever want to remove the DAZ app (directories) from your machine.

I recommend patience and aspirin.